# SQL How clarify a weird char in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl, chars

I have grabbed from a file source a column that suppose to be a DATE not more longer than 8 chars in a NVARCHAR(50) staging field. Now when I try to cast it to DATE it fails because SQL is not able to apply the transformation.

I tried to go deeper and understand what's going on and take a look the length. Among the remarkable things I realized that the len is always 9 and has at the end in VARBINARY 00D00. I added manually a new row how suppose to came the field and the len fit as I expect.

code:

```
SELECT  [LastPriceChange],len([LastPriceChange]), 
convert(varbinary(max),[LastPriceChange])
FROM  [STAGING].[MBEW]
group by [LastPriceChange]
order by 2 desc
```

Output:

[image]

I'm trying to get the final part to understand what is that thinking that is **00D00** but when I try :

```
SELECT REPLICATE(NCHAR(000D00), 5 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)
```

It doesnt go thru, some one have any clue about how should I figure it out?

thanks

Comment: `REPLICATE` repeats a string. Did you mean `REPLACE`?

Comment: Yes to try to see what it is in COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2

Comment: `0x0D` is a carriage return `\r`, `(char)13`. Just use `SUBSTRING(0,8)` to get rid of it. Could be that you read the file as unix format expecting a `\n`, i.e. a new line character `(char)10` as line separator.

Comment: checking @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Done it goes thru, could you please post your answer to tag it as done :) thanks

Comment: NVARCHAR means UTF-16 so every two bytes is a code unit. So, the question about 0D 00 (written as '\u000D' in some languages, which is the single code unit for the U+000D [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoint.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x0D` is a carriage return `'\r'`, `(char)13`. Just use `SUBSTRING(LastPriceChange, 0, 8)` to get rid of it.

Could it be that you read the file as Unix format expecting only a `'\n'` (new line character,  `(char)10`) as line separator instead of `"\r\n"` (carriage return + new line) as usual in Windows? This would explain why the `0x0D` was left over.

See: [ASCII, Control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) (Wikipedia).